# Weird behavior when changing directory name

Tags: fullcalendar

I have created something cool for my purposes here:

http://hinternet.com.au/projects/fullcalendar-1.4.8/index.php

To try to declutter it, I have cloned everything to a new directory named calendar:

http://hinternet.com.au/projects/calendar/index.php

Note how the header is being duplicated?  I can't figure out what is going on.  Any ideas?

FYI, this is loading and updating a mySQL db using ajax and json.  Pretty cool I reckon.

(Once I sort this problem out I have another question about removing an event)

Comment: That _is_ bizarre. I can't help you with the question but at least I can put the right link in for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you have only changed the folder name? Has there anything changed in index.php?

Comment: Yep, all I did was clone the folder with identical files.  To be honest I haven't trawled it looking for references to the folder name, but I would be surprised if there was something like that in the code.

Comment: Can you try changing the project name from "calendar" to something else like for e.g. "steve". I know its absurd but just give it a try.

Comment: sigh...now I can't reproduce it.  At least it is working :)  Thanks for your suggestion